# Simultaneously clustering discrete and continuous features with DBSCAN - confirmation this is setup correctly?

Tags: python, matplotlib, dbscan

This is my first attempt at using DBSCAN to cluster discrete (datapoint's bound width) and continuous features (computed css and path to datapoint) for text-content blocks I've extracted from a webpage.

I have 7 samples (in the first dataset), so when I set DBSCAN min_samples to 1, this output is what I would expect:

- Estimated number of clusters: 7
- Estimated number of noise points: 0
- Homogeneity: 1.000
- Completeness: 1.000

I've then attempted to plot the clusters in order to visualise them. For the plot, I've used the [sklearn example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_dbscan.html), adjusting it for my data. However, the resulting plot doesn't look quite right.

[image: dbscan plot with 7 clusters]

It looks like the y-axis values of most clusters are the same (-0.408). I believe this is down to using StandardScaler(), at this step:

```
feature_stack = np.hstack([continuous_features, discrete_features])
"""[[-1.31614507  0.          1.          1.          1.          1.          0.          0.          0.          0.          1.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          1.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          1.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          1.          0.          0.          0.          0.          1.          0.          0.          0.          0.          1.          0.          0.          0.          0.          1.          1.          0.          1.          0.          1.          0.          0.          0.          1.          0.          0.          0.          0.          1.          0.          1.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          1.          0.          0.          1.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          1.          0.          0.          0.          0.          1.          0.          0.          0.          0.          1.          1.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          1.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          1.          0.        ]
    [-0.66130166  0.          1.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          1.          0.          1.          0.          1.          0.          0.          0.          1.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          1.          0.          0.          0.          1.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          1.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          1.          0.          0.          0.          0.        ]"""
features = feature_stack.astype(np.float32)
"""[[-1.3161451   0.          1.          1.          1.          1.          0.          0.          0.          0.          1.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          1.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          1.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          1.          0.          0.          0.          0.          1.          0.          0.          0.          0.          1.          0.          0.          0.          0.          1.          1.          0.          1.          0.          1.          0.          0.          0.          1.          0.          0.          0.          0.          1.          0.          1.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          1.          0.          0.          1.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          1.          0.          0.          0.          0.          1.          0.          0.          0.          0.          1.          1.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          1.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          1.          0.        ]
    [-0.6613017   0.          1.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          1.          0.          1.          0.          1.          0.          0.          0.          1.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          1.          0.          0.          0.          1.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          1.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          1.          0.          0.          0.          0.        ]"""

# CLUSTER DATA
scaled_data = StandardScaler().fit_transform(features)
# scaled_data
# [[-1.3161452  -0.4082483   0.40824828  2.4494898   2.4494898   2.4494898  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483   2.4494898  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483   2.4494898  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483   2.4494898  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483   2.4494898  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483   2.4494898  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483   2.4494898  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483   1.581139    1.581139  -0.4082483   1.1547004  -0.4082483   1.581139   -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.6324555   1.581139   -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.6324555  -0.4082483   2.4494898  -0.4082483   2.4494898  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.6324556  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483   2.4494898  -0.4082483  -0.4082483   2.4494898  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -1.1547006   2.4494898  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483   2.4494898  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483   2.4494898   2.4494898  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483   2.4494898  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483   1.581139   -0.4082483 ]
#  [-0.66130173 -0.4082483   0.40824828 -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.6324556   1.581139  -0.4082483   1.1547004  -0.4082483   1.581139   -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.6324555   1.581139   -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.6324555  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483   2.4494898  -0.6324556  -0.4082483  -0.4082483   2.4494898  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483   2.4494898  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -1.1547006  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.4082483   2.4494898  -0.4082483  -0.4082483  -0.6324556  -0.4082483 ]
```

What can I do to improve my model?

Here's my complete code (including commented) to get the plot above:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Main
import os
import simplejson as json
import random
import processors
import tokenizers
import analyzers
import clusterers
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
from sklearn import svm, preprocessing, cross_validation
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_curve, auc, classification_report, precision_recall_fscore_support
import collections

# Processor
from sklearn import preprocessing

# DBSCAN
from sklearn import cluster
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import numpy as np


class Processor(object):

    CONTINUOUS_FEATURES = {
    'width': lambda page, datapoint: float(datapoint['bound']['width']),}

    def __init__(self, data):

        self.data = data
        self.pages = []
        self.texts = []

        for page in self.data:
            for text in page['texts']:
                self.pages.append(page)
                self.texts.append(text)

    def extract(self):

        continuous_features = []
        discrete_features = []

        for page, text in zip(self.pages, self.texts):

            continuous_features.append([process(page, text) for key, process in self.CONTINUOUS_FEATURES.iteritems()])

            discrete_feature = dict(text['computed'].items())
            discrete_feature['path'] = ' > '.join(text['path'])
            discrete_features.append(discrete_feature)

        return continuous_features, discrete_features



def load_data(file):
    with open(file) as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    return data


def main():

    data = [{'body': {'scroll': {'top': 0, 'left': 0}, 'bound': {'width': 3983, 'top': 0, 'height': 1526, 'left': 0}}, 'texts': [{'computed': {'font-size': '15px', 'text-decoration-color': 'rgb(0, 0, 0)', 'color': 'rgb(0, 0, 0)', 'transform-origin': '15px 13px', 'margin-right': '10px', 'border-left-color': 'rgb(0, 0, 0)', 'background-repeat': 'no-repeat', 'caret-color': 'rgb(0, 0, 0)', 'border-top-color': 'rgb(0, 0, 0)', 'background-color': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)', 'border-bottom-color': 'rgb(0, 0, 0)', 'outline-color': 'rgb(0, 0, 0)', 'border-right-color': 'rgb(0, 0, 0)', 'text-emphasis-color': 'rgb(0, 0, 0)', 'text-indent': '-9999px', 'unicode-bidi': 'normal', 'text-shadow': 'rgb(0, 0, 0) 0px 0px 0px', 'font-family': 'FuturaLight', 'background-image': 'url("file:///C:/Users/ronaldg/Documents/_Beauty/data/sites/adorebeauty/images/head/heart-icon.svg")', 'perspective-origin': '15px 13px', 'line-height': '20.25px', 'cursor': 'pointer', 'display': 'inline-block', 'column-rule-color': 'rgb(0, 0, 0)'}, 'text': ['Wishlist'], 'bound': {'width': 30, 'top': 30, 'height': 26, 'left': 2305.60009765625}, 'selector': [{'classes': ['wrapper'], 'id': '', 'name': 'div'}, {'classes': ['page'], 'id': '', 'name': 'div'}, {'classes': ['mage-header'], 'id': '', 'name': 'div'}, {'classes': [], 'id': 'header', 'name': 'header'}, {'classes': ['header-section'], 'id': '', 'name': 'div'}, {'classes': ['header-right-block'], 'id': '', 'name': 'div'}, {'classes': ['header-account'], 'id': 'header-account', 'name': 'div'}, {'classes': ['header-wishlist'], 'id': '', 'name': 'a'}], 'html': 'Wishlist', 'path': ['div', 'div', 'div', 'header', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'a'], 'element': {'classes': ['header-wishlist'], 'id': '', 'name': 'a'}}, {'computed': {'font-size': '15px', 'perspective-origin': '72.7px 15px', 'transform-origin': '72.7px 15px', 'display': 'inline-block', 'padding-top': '5px', 'font-family': 'FuturaLight', 'line-height': '20.25px', 'background-color': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)'}, 'text': ['Sign in', ' | ', 'Register'], 'bound': {'width': 145.39999389648438, 'top': 25, 'height': 30, 'left': 2303.60009765625}, 'selector': [{'classes': ['wrapper'], 'id': '', 'name': 'div'}, {'classes': ['page'], 'id': '', 'name': 'div'}, {'classes': ['mage-header'], 'id': '', 'name': 'div'}, {'classes': [], 'id': 'header', 'name': 'header'}, {'classes': ['header-section'], 'id': '', 'name': 'div'}, {'classes': ['header-right-block'], 'id': '', 'name': 'div'}, {'classes': ['header-account'], 'id': 'header-account', 'name': 'div'}], 'html': '\n                <!-- -->\n            <a href="https://www.adorebeauty.com.au/wishlist/" rel="nofollow" class="header-wishlist" style="border: 1px solid red;">Wishlist</a><a href="https://www.adorebeauty.com.au/customer/account/login/" rel="nofollow" class="login">Sign in</a> | <a href="https://www.adorebeauty.com.au/customer/account/create/" rel="nofollow">Register</a>', 'path': ['div', 'div', 'div', 'header', 'div', 'div', 'div'], 'element': {'classes': ['header-account'], 'id': 'header-account', 'name': 'div'}}, {'computed': {'border-top-style': 'solid', 'font-size': '14px', 'text-decoration-color': 'rgb(255, 255, 255)', 'color': 'rgb(255, 255, 255)', 'letter-spacing': '1px', 'transform-origin': '95.0833px 22.5px', 'padding-bottom': '12px', 'padding-top': '12px', 'border-top-width': '1px', 'border-left-color': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)', 'border-right-style': 'solid', 'padding-right': '18px', 'border-left-style': 'solid', 'caret-color': 'rgb(255, 255, 255)', 'border-top-color': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)', 'background-color': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)', 'border-bottom-color': 'rgb(255, 255, 255)', 'outline-color': 'rgb(255, 255, 255)', 'border-right-color': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)', 'text-emphasis-color': 'rgb(255, 255, 255)', 'unicode-bidi': 'normal', 'text-shadow': 'rgb(255, 255, 255) 0px 0px 0px', 'list-style-type': 'none', 'font-family': 'FuturaLight', 'text-align': 'left', 'perspective-origin': '95.0833px 22.5px', 'cursor': 'pointer', 'border-right-width': '1px', 'column-rule-color': 'rgb(255, 255, 255)', 'text-transform': 'uppercase', 'line-height': '20px', 'border-left-width': '1px', 'padding-left': '18px'}, 'text': ['Shop By Category'], 'bound': {'width': 190.1666717529297, 'top': 80, 'height': 45, 'left': 1499}, 'selector': [{'classes': ['wrapper'], 'id': '', 'name': 'div'}, {'classes': ['page'], 'id': '', 'name': 'div'}, {'classes': ['nav-head'], 'id': '', 'name': 'nav'}, {'classes': ['top-nav'], 'id': 'top-nav', 'name': 'ul'}, {'classes': ['cat-item', 'top'], 'id': '', 'name': 'li'}, {'classes': [], 'id': '', 'name': 'a'}], 'html': 'Shop By Category', 'path': ['div', 'div', 'nav', 'ul', 'li', 'a'], 'element': {'classes': [], 'id': '', 'name': 'a'}}, {'computed': {'font-size': '16px', 'text-decoration-color': 'rgb(20, 179, 88)', 'color': 'rgb(20, 179, 88)', 'transform-origin': '270px 25.5333px', 'padding-bottom': '10px', 'padding-top': '10px', 'border-left-color': 'rgb(20, 179, 88)', 'margin-bottom': '28px', 'padding-right': '10px', 'caret-color': 'rgb(20, 179, 88)', 'border-top-color': 'rgb(20, 179, 88)', 'background-color': 'rgb(234, 248, 248)', 'border-bottom-color': 'rgb(20, 179, 88)', 'outline-color': 'rgb(20, 179, 88)', 'border-right-color': 'rgb(20, 179, 88)', 'text-emphasis-color': 'rgb(20, 179, 88)', 'text-shadow': 'rgb(20, 179, 88) 0px 0px 0px', 'perspective-origin': '270px 25.5333px', 'margin-top': '22px', 'line-height': '21.6px', 'column-rule-color': 'rgb(20, 179, 88)', 'padding-left': '10px'}, 'text': [u'\u2714\ufe0e ', 'In Stock.', '\n                                                                                    We ship today if you order before ', '3 am'], 'bound': {'width': 540, 'top': 479.9666748046875, 'height': 51.05000305175781, 'left': 1921.5}, 'selector': [{'classes': ['wrapper'], 'id': '', 'name': 'div'}, {'classes': ['page'], 'id': '', 'name': 'div'}, {'classes': ['col1-layout', 'main'], 'id': '', 'name': 'div'}, {'classes': ['col-main'], 'id': '', 'name': 'div'}, {'classes': [], 'id': '', 'name': 'div'}, {'classes': ['product-view'], 'id': '', 'name': 'div'}, {'classes': [], 'id': 'product_addtocart_form', 'name': 'form'}, {'classes': ['product-essential'], 'id': '', 'name': 'div'}, {'classes': ['product-shop'], 'id': 'product-shop', 'name': 'div'}, {'classes': ['add-to-box'], 'id': '', 'name': 'div'}, {'classes': ['is-before', 'new-in-stock'], 'id': '', 'name': 'div'}], 'html': u'\n                                        <span><span class="tick">\u2714\ufe0e </span>In Stock.</span>\n                                                                                    We ship today if you order before <span class="time" data-time="1539262800000">3 am</span>                                                                            ', 'path': ['div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'form', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div'], 'element': {'classes': ['is-before', 'new-in-stock'], 'id': '', 'name': 'div'}}, {'computed': {'float': 'left', 'transform-origin': '135px 18.5833px', 'perspective-origin': '135px 18.5833px', 'background-color': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)', 'text-align': 'left'}, 'text': ['Qty'], 'bound': {'width': 270, 'top': 561.0166625976562, 'height': 37.15000915527344, 'left': 1921.5}, 'selector': [{'classes': ['wrapper'], 'id': '', 'name': 'div'}, {'classes': ['page'], 'id': '', 'name': 'div'}, {'classes': ['col1-layout', 'main'], 'id': '', 'name': 'div'}, {'classes': ['col-main'], 'id': '', 'name': 'div'}, {'classes': [], 'id': '', 'name': 'div'}, {'classes': ['product-view'], 'id': '', 'name': 'div'}, {'classes': [], 'id': 'product_addtocart_form', 'name': 'form'}, {'classes': ['product-essential'], 'id': '', 'name': 'div'}, {'classes': ['product-shop'], 'id': 'product-shop', 'name': 'div'}, {'classes': ['add-to-box'], 'id': '', 'name': 'div'}, {'classes': ['add-to-cart'], 'id': '', 'name': 'div'}], 'html': '\n\t<label for="qty">Qty</label>\n\t<select name="qty" id="qty" class="hasCustomSelect" style="-webkit-appearance: menulist-button; width: 60px; position: absolute; opacity: 0; height: 36px; font-size: 11px; left: 0px;">\n\t\t<option value="1" selected="">1</option>\n        \t\t<option value="2">2</option>\n        \t\t<option value="3">3</option>\n        \t\t<option value="4">4</option>\n        \t\t<option value="5">5</option>\n        \t\t<option value="6">6</option>\n        \t\t<option value="7">7</option>\n        \t\t<option value="8">8</option>\n        \t\t<option value="9">9</option>\n        \t\t<option value="10">10</option>\n        \t</select><span class="customSelect" style="display: inline-block;"><span class="customSelectInner" style="width: 49px; display: inline-block;">1</span></span>\n\t\t<button type="button" title="Add to Bag" class="button btn-cart"><span><span>Add to Bag</span></span></button>\n\t\t', 'path': ['div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'form', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div'], 'element': {'classes': ['add-to-cart'], 'id': '', 'name': 'div'}}, {'computed': {'text-decoration-color': 'rgb(102, 102, 102)', 'outline-color': 'rgb(102, 102, 102)', 'border-left-color': 'rgb(102, 102, 102)', 'perspective-origin': '250px 35px', 'color': 'rgb(102, 102, 102)', 'border-right-color': 'rgb(102, 102, 102)', 'text-emphasis-color': 'rgb(102, 102, 102)', 'transform-origin': '250px 35px', 'text-shadow': 'rgb(102, 102, 102) 0px 0px 0px', 'background-color': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)', 'caret-color': 'rgb(102, 102, 102)', 'border-top-color': 'rgb(102, 102, 102)', 'border-bottom-color': 'rgb(102, 102, 102)', 'line-height': '14px', 'column-rule-color': 'rgb(102, 102, 102)', 'text-align': 'left'}, 'text': [u"Skin is visibly restored by morning, as added\xa0Lavender Essential Oil works to soothe inflamed skin and promote an even skin tone,\xa0 Evening Primrose Oil helps to repair skin and Squalane replenishes skin's\xa0moisture barrier, leaving skin feeling soft, supple and moisturised.\xa0This restoring facial serum improves firmness and elasticity while encouraging a radiant, youthful complexion.\xa0"], 'bound': {'width': 500, 'top': 734.1666870117188, 'height': 70, 'left': 1937.5}, 'selector': [{'classes': ['wrapper'], 'id': '', 'name': 'div'}, {'classes': ['page'], 'id': '', 'name': 'div'}, {'classes': ['col1-layout', 'main'], 'id': '', 'name': 'div'}, {'classes': ['col-main'], 'id': '', 'name': 'div'}, {'classes': [], 'id': '', 'name': 'div'}, {'classes': ['product-view'], 'id': '', 'name': 'div'}, {'classes': [], 'id': 'product_addtocart_form', 'name': 'form'}, {'classes': ['product-collateral'], 'id': '', 'name': 'div'}, {'classes': ['collateral-tabs', 'tab-list'], 'id': 'collateral-tabs', 'name': 'dl'}, {'classes': ['tab-container'], 'id': '', 'name': 'dd'}, {'classes': ['jspScrollable', 'tab-content'], 'id': '', 'name': 'div'}, {'classes': ['jspContainer'], 'id': '', 'name': 'div'}, {'classes': ['jspPane'], 'id': '', 'name': 'div'}, {'classes': ['jspContainer'], 'id': '', 'name': 'div'}, {'classes': ['jspPane'], 'id': '', 'name': 'div'}, {'classes': [], 'id': '', 'name': 'p'}], 'html': "Skin is visibly restored by morning, as added&nbsp;Lavender Essential Oil works to soothe inflamed skin and promote an even skin tone,&nbsp; Evening Primrose Oil helps to repair skin and Squalane replenishes skin's&nbsp;moisture barrier, leaving skin feeling soft, supple and moisturised.&nbsp;This restoring facial serum improves firmness and elasticity while encouraging a radiant, youthful complexion.&nbsp;<br><br>", 'path': ['div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'form', 'div', 'dl', 'dd', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'p'], 'element': {'classes': [], 'id': '', 'name': 'p'}}, {'computed': {'text-decoration-color': 'rgb(153, 153, 153)', 'outline-color': 'rgb(153, 153, 153)', 'line-height': '14px', 'vertical-align': 'top', 'perspective-origin': '79px 7px', 'color': 'rgb(153, 153, 153)', 'border-right-color': 'rgb(153, 153, 153)', 'text-emphasis-color': 'rgb(153, 153, 153)', 'transform-origin': '79px 7px', 'text-shadow': 'rgb(153, 153, 153) 0px 0px 0px', 'background-color': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)', 'border-left-color': 'rgb(153, 153, 153)', 'caret-color': 'rgb(153, 153, 153)', 'list-style-type': 'none', 'border-bottom-color': 'rgb(153, 153, 153)', 'border-top-color': 'rgb(153, 153, 153)', 'column-rule-color': 'rgb(153, 153, 153)', 'text-align': 'left'}, 'text': ['Free over $50'], 'bound': {'width': 158, 'top': 1910.75, 'height': 14, 'left': 1995.5}, 'selector': [{'classes': ['wrapper'], 'id': '', 'name': 'div'}, {'classes': ['page'], 'id': '', 'name': 'div'}, {'classes': ['footer-container'], 'id': '', 'name': 'div'}, {'classes': ['footer'], 'id': '', 'name': 'div'}, {'classes': ['footer-links-icons'], 'id': '', 'name': 'div'}, {'classes': ['footer-links'], 'id': '', 'name': 'div'}, {'classes': [], 'id': '', 'name': 'ul'}, {'classes': [], 'id': '', 'name': 'li'}], 'html': 'Free over $50', 'path': ['div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'ul', 'li'], 'element': {'classes': [], 'id': '', 'name': 'li'}}]}]

    # PROCESS DATA
    processor = Processor(data)
    raw_continuous_features, raw_discrete_features = processor.extract()

    # ENCODE
    continuous_features = np.array(raw_continuous_features)
    scaled_continuous_features = preprocessing.scale(continuous_features)

    DV = DictVectorizer()

    discrete_features = DV.fit_transform(raw_discrete_features).toarray()

    features = np.hstack([continuous_features, discrete_features]).astype(np.float32)

    # CLUSTER DATA
    data = StandardScaler().fit_transform(features)
    db = cluster.DBSCAN(eps=0.5, min_samples=1).fit(data)


    ############################### DBSCAN PLOT DEMO/EXAMPLE ###############################

    from sklearn import metrics

    core_samples_mask = np.zeros_like(db.labels_, dtype=bool)
    core_samples_mask[db.core_sample_indices_] = True
    labels = db.labels_

    # Number of clusters in labels, ignoring noise if present.
    n_clusters_ = len(set(labels)) - (1 if -1 in labels else 0)
    n_noise_ = list(labels).count(-1)

    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    # Black removed and is used for noise instead.
    unique_labels = set(labels)
    colors = [plt.cm.Spectral(each)
              for each in np.linspace(0, 1, len(unique_labels))]
    for k, col in zip(unique_labels, colors):
        if k == -1:
            # Black used for noise.
            col = [0, 0, 0, 1]

        class_member_mask = (labels == k)

        xy = data[class_member_mask & core_samples_mask]
        plt.plot(xy[:, 0], xy[:, 1], 'o', markerfacecolor=tuple(col),
                 markeredgecolor='k', markersize=14)

        xy = data[class_member_mask & ~core_samples_mask]
        plt.plot(xy[:, 0], xy[:, 1], 'o', markerfacecolor=tuple(col),
                 markeredgecolor='k', markersize=6)

    plt.title('Estimated number of clusters: %d' % n_clusters_)
    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Appreciate any help/tips/pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't actually cluster. With as many clusters as data points, you just have the original data... DBSCAN does not make much sense on data with just 7 samples - nothing is "dense" there.

But your actual question is about the standard scaler.

If you encode a categorical attribute as 0 or 1 binary variables, and then apply the standard scaler, 0 will become some negative value, and 1 will be a positive (usually different) value.

Now in your case, there is only one point with that particular value.

That shows why the entire one-hot encoding and standard scaling approach is actually a pretty bad hack. The proper way to use categoricial data with DBSCAN is to either A) define a distance defined on this data - no need to transform the data into vectors - or B) to define appropriate neighbor predicates as detailed in the Generalized DBSCAN follow-up paper for extra control.

Comment: OK... I did realise I only added one set of data points. Your comments were useful though, I have something to look into. Thank you